# Using an <aside> inside of a <nav> element?

Tags: html

Would it be semantically correct to use an aside element inside of a nav?

I am creating a drop down mega menu on an ecommerce site, which will have an area on the side of the drop down that will be used to promote a particular product.

This isn't strictly part of the hierarchal navigation, but will be related to the parent in the navigational tree.

Similar to below:

```
<nav>
  <ul>

    <li>Link 1
      <div class='mega-menu'>
        <ul>
          <li>child link</li>
          <li>child link</li>
          <li>child link</li>
        </ul>

        <aside>
          /* Promo content in here */
        </aside>

      </div>
   </li>

   <li>Link 2</li>
   <li>Link 3</li>
   <li>Link 4</li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

In this circumstance would it be correct to use an aside?

Thanks in advance for any advice, cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an aside element into a nav element is permitted as you can see in the following link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav where it is said : *Permitted content : Flow content.*

If you open the flow content page, you can see that an aside element is effectively a flow content : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content

Comment: great - the info was staring me right in the face all along. Thanks for pointing out, what is now the obvious, permitted content: flow content